# MySQL can't add foreign key error

Tags: mysql

```
  CREATE TABLE People
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Company_Name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    Predicted_Pos VARCHAR(20),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),

);

INSERT INTO People VALUES (1, 'Shujun Li', '3rd');

CREATE TABLE Driver
(
    ID INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    First_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    Last_name VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    Car_make VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    Car_model VARCHAR(256) NOT NULL,
    People_ID INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID),   
    FOREIGN KEY(People_ID) REFERENCES People(ID)

);

INSERT INTO People VALUES (1, 'Shujun Li', 'bob', 'merc', 'benz', 1);
```

Comment: Could we get some error message ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) to learn what we expect from questions. In its current form your question is unanswerable. Please gather extra information and then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27725802/edit) your post.

Comment: So, what's the error?  What are you trying to do?  Does this SQL work?  Not work?  Which part is or isn't working?  Which table(s) are you trying to add a foreign key to?  We need more than just an SQL file, there's not even a question here!

Comment: This sql doesn't work. I am trying to create a database to show the companies in the 'f1' which is one table. Then i have driver manager team and race tables and am trying to link them together. Such as if you click on the driver id in the manager table it will take you to the the driver table to show you his details. Sorry for being so vague, this is my first post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some circular references in your schema. The `People` table depends on the `Driver` table and the `Driver` table depends on the `People` table. You can never insert a record into one of the tables without having a row in the other first, an impossible, chicken n' egg situation. There are other examples of circular references in your schema. Remove all circular references from your schema.

Comment: I am completely brand new to mysql and what I gather from your post is that I should delete the circular references? I get the 1215 error and I would like to be able to click on a driver's id which would take me to his manager etc but am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Yes. You can start by removing the `Driver_ID` and `Manager_ID` columns from the `People` table. Those relationships are already defined by virtue of the foreign keys in their respective child tables.

Comment: May I ask where the other circular references are so i may remove them.

Comment: The last `FOREIGN KEY` statement in the `Team` table makes it look as though `Team` depends on itself. Also, it references a non-existent column. Unless the column is nullable and this is a parent/child relationship, you should probably remove that.

Comment: Ive deleted everything and now am trying to connect the people table to the driver table, by way of a foreign key in the driver table. This is what i have so far